# mysql-update multiple columns in a single row with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a mysql table as follows:

```
name | serialno | key
---------------------
NULL | NULL     | 10
luke | 1234     | 20
NULL | NULL     | 30
NULL | NULL     | 40
```

I have to update a row where the `name` and the `serialno` update for a valid key.

The update statements that I am running are as follows:

```
UPDATE test SET Name = 'pc', Serialno = '10', WHERE `Key` = '10' AND name is null
```

and

```
UPDATE test SET Name = CASE
WHEN NULL THEN 'pc'
END
SET Serialno = CASE
WHEN NULL THEN '10'
END
Where `key` = '20'
```

The following errors get displayed:

1.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Key = '10' AND name is null' at line 1:
```

2.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Serial = CASE
WHEN NULL THEN '10'
END
Where `key`='20'' at line 4:
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test SET Name = CASE Name
WHEN NULL THEN 'pc'
END,
SET Serialno = CASE Serialno 
WHEN NULL THEN '10'
END
Where `key` = '20'
```

You have to specify condition of your CASE

Comment: Thanks, I tried this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and I'm getting this error:

`Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Serial = CASE Serial
WHEN NULL THEN '10'
END
Where `key` = '20'' at line 4:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what is the context (can you explain the detail what you want and then I will help you with better result).

However, as the StanislavL's answer, the syntax was wrong. I corrected it as below:

```
UPDATE test SET Name = CASE Name
WHEN NULL THEN 'pc'
END,
Serialno = CASE Serialno 
WHEN NULL THEN '10'
END
Where `key` = '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for Errors:

**Error 1** was because you have a `,` *comma* before `WHERE Key = '10' ...`.
Statement should be:

```
UPDATE test SET Name = 'pc', Serialno = '10' WHERE `Key` = '10' AND name is null
```

**Error 2** was because you have not instructed which *case value* to check in `when` clause. Acceptable syntaxes are:

```
1. CASE column_name WHEN value THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END  

2. CASE WHEN column_name <condition> value THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END
```

Statement should be:

```
UPDATE test 
SET
    Name     = CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 'pc' else name end
  , Serialno = CASE WHEN serialno IS NULL THEN '10' else serialno end
END
Where `key` = '10'
```

**Example** @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04f97d/1)

You can extend this to set values for columns based on different `key` values without using `where` clause.

**Example**:

```
UPDATE test 
SET
    Name     = CASE WHEN `key`=10 and name IS NULL THEN 'pc' else name end
  , Serialno = CASE WHEN `key`=10 and serialno IS NULL THEN '10' else serialno end

  , Name     = CASE WHEN `key`=30 and name IS NULL THEN 'key is 30' else name end
  , Serialno = CASE WHEN `key`=30 and serialno IS NULL THEN '3' else serialno end
END
```

**Refer to**: [**MySQL: CASE - WHEN syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this

```
UPDATE test SET Name = 'pc', Serialno = '10' WHERE `Key` = '10' AND name is null
```